# Extract years from column of date strings in a pandas column

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a dataset that has a date column:

```
df.faultDate.head()

0    2014-07-13
1    2014-07-13
2    2014-07-12
3    2014-07-12
4    2014-07-13
```

I am trying to get just years from that.

```
dt.datetime.strptime(df.faultDate[0], '%Y-%m-%d').year

2014
```

But:

```
df.faultDate.apply(dt.datetime.strptime, args=('%Y-%m-%d'))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-bca0dc79125b> in <module>()
----> 1 df.faultDate.apply(dt.datetime.strptime, args=('%Y-%m-%d'))

/home/shiny/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2058             values = lib.map_infer(values, lib.Timestamp)
   2059 
-> 2060         mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2061         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
   2062             from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame

pandas/src/inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:58435)()

/home/shiny/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in <lambda>(x)
   2047 
   2048         if kwds or args and not isinstance(func, np.ufunc):
-> 2049             f = lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwds)
   2050         else:
   2051             f = func

TypeError: strptime() takes exactly 2 arguments (9 given)
```

I am also not sure how to pass `.year` argument after I successfully convert the strings into datetimes. I could write a wrapper function that takes each row as input and then extracts the year, but I think it’s useful to know how to apply pandas syntax for future reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method #1 (better, IMHO): treat it as a date parsing problem, after which we can use the `.dt` vectorized time accessor.

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df.faultDate).dt.year
0    2014
1    2014
2    2014
3    2014
4    2014
dtype: int64
```

where we can specify the format if we want:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df.faultDate, format="%Y-%m-%d").dt.year
0    2014
1    2014
2    2014
3    2014
4    2014
dtype: int64
```

Method #2: treat it as a string parsing problem.  Less natural in some ways, but as an example of tricks which can come in handy on other occasions, not bad.  We can use vectorized string operations:

```
>>> df.faultDate.str[:4].astype(int)
0    2014
1    2014
2    2014
3    2014
4    2014
Name: faultDate, dtype: int64
>>> df.faultDate.str.split("-").str[0].astype(int)
0    2014
1    2014
2    2014
3    2014
4    2014
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the first version.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to call against the actual object, not the entire file:

```
dt.datetime.strptime(df.faultDate[0], '%Y-%m-%d').year
```

Turns into

```
(df.faultDate[0]).apply(dt.datetime.strptime, args=('%Y-%m-%d’))
```

Note that subscript!